# How the basic structure of a simple messaging app works?

Tags: python, networking, communication, ftp

How the messaging apps works?
What is the Basic algorithm of it?
I tried the following method to make a messaging app.

1. I enters message
2. Message converts to a text file
3. Text text file uploads to the ftp server
4. My friend gets the text file from ftp and reads it

Is this method correct?
Do needed to use FTP server?
I found it is very slow and sometimes it gets timeout Error.
What is wrong here? Is my method wrong or the problem is the server?

Comment: FTP is probably the slowest protocol you can choose for that, and will also come with numerous limitations. I'd rather choose something (also) TCP/IP based without file transfers involved. There are tons of better suited protocols available, and also many resources and examples you can find about these in the internet.

Comment: FTP is one of the worst delivery mechanisms you could have picked for this application. Worse than it? Probably, a USB drive or a letter. The good news is, there are a ton of delivery technologies quick, easy, and very performant for you to adapt to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The messaging app company writes their own server with their own protocol.

The client connects to the server all the time (not just when you're sending a message). When you send a message, it sends the message to the server using the app's protocol, and the server sends the message to the other user using the app's protocol. If the other user isn't online, the server stores the message and sends it to them when they are online.